# ActionController::UnknownFormat Error for only format.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am simply using -

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

in my create action. Don't know why but i am getting an the UnknownFormat error. The error is gone if i put in both "format.html" and "format.js". But i want to stay in the same page and make an ajax call. I have gone through like 5 pages of google search results for every possible search and still nothing works for me. Can anyone help me out here?

My form is like this -

```
<%= form_for [:home, Photo.new], remote: true, :html => {:id => "new-photo-form"} do |f| %>

    <div id="upload-field">
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>

    <%= f.hidden_field :album_id, :value => album.id %>

    <div id="photo-add-link">
        <%= link_to 'Add Selected Images', '#', remote: true, :onclick => "$('#new-photo-form').submit()" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

server logs -

```
Started POST "/home/photos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-28 08:23:38 +0530
Processing by Home::PhotosController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "photo"=>{"image"=>#  <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd5541a0578 @tempfile=#  <Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20161228-6069-175ahz0.jpg>,   @original_filename="emilia-clark.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\";   filename=\"emilia-clark.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,   "album_id"=>"68"}}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
app/controllers/home/photos_controller.rb:11:in `create'


Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.4ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-  4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (16.2ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.2ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (16.2ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
Rendered /home/santhosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-  2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (29.5ms)
```

Comment: where is the script?

Comment: Kindly post the appropriate script/code.

Comment: That is all the code

Comment: and create.js.erb file contains only - alert("This is working");

Comment: Would the user who down voted my question could please remove it? I mean this is a big problem to me and it would be very useful to me if i could solve it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are using a file_field in your form. JavaScript doesn't have access to your filesystem, so you can't create an ajax request to upload files. There are some gems to workaround this. check [this](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) gem.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe that is the problem. There are many gems that are used for ajax file uploads. Thanks very much. I will look it up.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your guess is right. The file upload field was the reason it was giving me that error. I added the "remotipart" gem in my Gemfile and //= require jquery.remotipart